# Is it possible for the app to open already with the latest data obtained by firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter, dart

Every time I close my application it has to load the data from the firebase again. Is there any way for it to already open with the last data fetched?

Comment: You can use `sqflite` package to cache the data offline. But that will be fairly complex, even unnecessary if the size of the data is small.

Comment: show at least you have tried

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should explain a bit more, so we understand your use case. Anyways, i'll try to answer with what I have understood.

You can use `sqflite` package to cache the data, i.e. it will be stored to the local storage. Get started: https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite

It will be fairly complex, even unnecessary if the size of your data is small.

If you have huge amount of data that doesn't change frequently, then go for it.

So how it will work is like this:

First you'll check whether the data has changed in Firestore or not.

**Case 1:** If it didn't then you'll display data from your local sqflite db.

**Case 2:** If it did change, then, you'll display data from Firestore, and at the same time update your local db with the new data.

Again, this is very superfluous if your data size is be small/it changes very frequently.

Comment: @vagnerwilliam Firebase has Disk Persistence so while this is an interesting answer, it's soooo much easier to turn on Disk Persistence and call it a day.

Comment: @Jay I agree. Should I delete my answer? So that others don't get misguided as my answer has been accepted.

Comment: It's an answer, just not the best answer. It may give future readers another option to consider so I would leave it.

Answer (score 1):

If you enable disk persistence, the Firebase client will write any data it sees to a local disk cache. This means that when you restart the app when there's no connectivity, the same data that you saw before is available offline on your app.

For more info, see the Firebase documentation on [disk persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-disk-persistence) and the call to enable it from [Flutter](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/FirebaseDatabase/setPersistenceEnabled.html).